# Changing 0 to NULL in QGIS Attribute table

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, attribute-table, null

I am using QGIS 3.4 and I want to change all my `0` values to `NULL`. How can I do that in the attribute table?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?  Please [Edit] the question.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 8):

- select all your '0' rows -> Go to 'Select by expression' and select all rows where attribute = 0
- Go to 'Field calculator' and check 'Update existing field', 'Only update selected features' and select your field = NULL

Answer (score 6):

After selecting the layer, use this script in the QGIS's Python Editor (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>):

```py
from qgis.utils import iface

layer = iface.activeLayer()

idx = range(layer.fields().count())

layer.startEditing()

for f in layer.getFeatures():
    attr_map = {i: NULL for i in idx if f[i] == 0}
    layer.changeAttributeValues(f.id(), attr_map)
    
layer.commitChanges()
```

This script changes all zeros in all columns to `NULL`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Or if you do not want to select all features manually or dont want to use PyQGIS, you can simply use `if()` or `case when`, like:

```
if("field" = 0,NULL,"field")
```

or

```
case
when "field" = 0 then NULL
else "field"
end
```

Don't forget to set the checkmark on "Update existing field":

[image]